# Как сделать отчет аналогичный отчету по источникам в Analytics/Метрике

Tags: mysql

я использую Laravel в своем приложении.

У меня есть модель - Session, которая связана с таблицей sessions в базе, в этой таблице есть поля: id, utm_source, calls, created_at

Я хочу сделать отчет аналогичный отчету analytics:

```
utm_source | сессии | звонки
yand       |   22   |    5
goog       |   38   |    1
bing       |   5    |    2
```

То-есть увидеть сколько по каждому utm_source было в сумме сессий,  а также сколько в сумме было звонков, за период времени между 2-мя датами.

Как мне правильно получить правильно получить эту информацию из базы.

Заранее спасибо за ответы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что пишется в поле calls?

Comment: Что такое "сессия" и что такое "звонок" с точки зрения хранящихся в таблице данных? лучше всего продемонстрируйте на примере набора значений для нескольких записей.

Comment: В поле calls пишется целое число, количество звонков, которое было у этой сессии.

С точки зрения хранения в таблице, сессия это одна запись со своим id. calls это поле, которое есть у этой записи.
Я посетитель, зашел на сайт с источника yand и позвонил 1 раз, тогда в таблице sessions создалась новая запись где:
utm_source: yand;
calls: 1;
createad_at: время создания записи (захода на сайт);

Comment: Я обновил вопрос и добавил к нему пример таблицы и результата, который хотелось бы получить. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, все получилось простым запросом.

`$results = DB::select('SELECT utm_source AS источник, COUNT(utm_source) AS количество_сессий, SUM(calls) AS количество_звонков FROM sessions WHERE date(created_at) >= '2019-03-13' AND date(created_at) <= '2019-03-14' GROUP BY utm_source');`

Спасибо